# Python error: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm writing a program to change ID by names, and I'm encountering the following problem

Problem:

```
        listanomes[count][1] = contatonoma[count][1]
    TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Code:

```
contactName = [('1', 'Yan'), ('2', 'Carl'),('3', 'Ana'), ('4', 'Maggie')]
nameList = [('Name', '1'), ('Name', '2'),('Name', '3'), ('Name', '4')]

count = 0
while count <= len(nameList):
    if nameList[count][1] == contactName[count][0]:
        nameList[count][1] = contactName[count][1]
    count += 1
print(nameList)
```

Comment: You cant assign a value to a tuple as they are not mutable. Try a list `x = [['hi','hello'],['bye','adios']]`

Comment: Hello @BuddyBob Thank you very much for the tip, I made the change and it worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

With the help of BuddyBob, I managed to solve the problem, in case anyone has the same problem as me, below is the example of the code working:

```
contactName = [['1', 'Yan'], ['2', 'Carl'],['3', 'Ana'], ['4', 'Maggie']]
nameList = [['Name', '1'], ['Name', '2'],['Name', '3'], ['Name', '4']]

count = 0
while count < len(nameList):
    if nameList[count][1] == contactName[count][0]:
        nameList[count][1] = contactName[count][1]
    count += 1
print(nameList)
```

Result:

```
[['Name', 'Yan'], ['Name', 'Carl'], ['Name', 'Ana'], ['Name', 'Maggie']]
```